# Open TabBar subview

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbar, segue

I got 2 subviews in a TabBar app. I should go to the 1st view from the 2nd, but not with help of tabbar, but throught another button, which is on the 2nd view.

If i create simple segue (between bytton on the 2nd view and the 1st view), tabbar will think, that i am still on the 2nd view and the 2nd button on the tabbar still highlighted.

Do you know correct way to realise it?

Comment: Do you want to change your view without touching tabbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your view without touching tababr controller

use this line of code where you want to use

self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

using this line you can move the 2 tab of the tabcontroller without touching tabbar.

Comment: Who dislike this post? It is really cool for me! Thnx, @KAREEM

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [UITabBarController.selectedViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property instead of segue.

Comment: thnx, this property is really what i need